# drawImage in Java applet flickers in Safari

Tags: java, macos, safari, applet, flicker

I'm having a flicker problem in a Java applet in Safari (Mac). However, it's not the usual double buffering problem.

I have isolated it down to one single `drawImage` call (no redundant repaint, no `clear` is called), which gives a white flicker before painting the image but not on every repaint. In fact, I measured the duration of the `drawImage` call, which is normally about 1ms, but up to 30ms about every 5th time paint is called, which is when it flickers. Repaints are triggered when I drag a component or when the window is scrolled.

Is this a bug in the java implementation on OSX, and is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

You give very small information. That is difficult to answer.

Do you recreate the Image before you paint it? Then you can buffer it or use an media tracker.

If you use an old Java version then update it. The old versions for OSX are very buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that your problem is the generic flickering applet problem.

the solution is there: [BackBuffer](http://profs.etsmtl.ca/mmcguffin/learn/java/07-backbuffer/)

i hope it helps.